# Typescript generics destruct and spread problem

Tags: typescript

I have problem with destructing parameter and creating new object of the same type in Typescript.

This code works:

```
function func<T extends { attr: string }>(param: T): T {
  const { ...rest } = param;
  return { ...rest };
}
```

while this code does not work:

```
function func<T extends { attr: string }>(param: T): T {
  const { attr, ...rest } = param;
  return { attr, ...rest };
}
```

The error message is:

```
Type '{ attr: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "attr">>' is not assignable to type 'T'
```

Could somebody explain, what is the problem here?

Comment: I think this github issue is related to whats going on here with the generic type: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884 I'm not 100% sure it's related, but if it is then there should be a fix "soon".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigating according to
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29081 the syntax is now supported with a slight modification:

```
function func<T extends { attr: string }>(param: T): T {
  const { attr, ...rest } = param;
  return { attr, ...rest } as T;
}
```

the **as T** assertion is necessary for the time being according to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884#issuecomment-448356158

Answer (score 0):

Here's I think a simplified demonstration of the issue.

```
function func2<T extends { a: string, b: string }>(param: T)
    : { a: string, b: string } {
    const { a, ...rest } = param;
    const x = rest.b; // Property 'b' does not exist on type 'Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "a">>'.
    return { a, ...rest }; // Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: string; } & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "a">>' 
                           // but required in type '{ a: string; b: string; }'.
}
```

Looks to be related to this recent addition of "Generic spread expressions in object literals" in 3.2: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28234

[Seems like a bug to me.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28234#issuecomment-452282851)

Comment: Thanks, I followed @AndyJ comment on my question and tried the newest (3.3.0-dev20190108) Typescript. Your example is working now, but mine does not. The difference is in the return type: whereas you have a fix definition { a: string, b: string } I reused the T generic.